# Position element relative to another doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to position my element with class name "adsense" over the half height of element with class name "publish-info" but it doesn't work. I should mention that I can't edit the html source of my template. I've tried this code:

```
.publish-info {
    height: 150px!important;
    position: relative!important;
}

.adsense {
    top: 50px!important;
    position: absolute!important;
}
```

...and javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    window.onload = function () {
        $('.publish-info').append($('.adsense'));
    } //]]>
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. Here's my site: http://www.musicep.com/2013/07/bt-aqualung-surrounded.html

Comment: I don't see your `.adsense` element on your site?

Comment: I foudn the .pubish-info element but it does not have the styles here. And no .adsense element below. Maybe you create a jsfiddle for isolation if this issue.

Comment: `.adsense` isn't a child of `.publish-info`, relative positioning doesn't work the way you think it does. With your code `.adsense` being absolutely positioned will be positioned 50px below its closest ancestor being positioned. And if none of its ancestors is positioned, then `body` will be the reference for positioning

Comment: @StephanMuller @citykid `.adsense` is on the right of the post (hint: you must deactivate ABP) and `.publish-info` is the date below the post *Posted (...)*

Comment: Thanks, I actually had ABP running, just figured that out D:

Comment: Thank you FelipeAls! Is not possible somehow to make with javascript or css publish-info parent?

Comment: You javascript is already doing that, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Your script and styles are doing roughly what they should do, but the problem is that the javascript function that places the `.adsense` element inside your `.publish-info` runs before  the adsense div is available.

Since you're using jQuery anyway, I'd suggest changing the `window.onload` to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.publish-info').append($('.adsense'));
});
```

See if that helps.